# enumerate in tcolorbox: weird insets

Tags: lists, margins, tcolorbox, dramatist

I'm typesetting text within `tcolorbox`-boxes, which works quite fine. For doing so, I've defined a couple of commands and just call them for each paragraph. But when I include an `enumerate`- or `itemize`-List in such a `tcolorbox`, the first item of the first is set much more left than the following items, this is really weird. Even more weird, when I include another list before my desired list in the `tcolorbox`, it works quite well for the second list:

[image]

So it's only the first list that's set wrongly. How can this be? Here's a MWE for my problem.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %Dummes Absatz-Eingerücke abstellen

\newcommand{\sep}{\\[3mm]}

\newcommand{\ex}[1]{\item\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Lorem Ipsum,colframe=Orange1]#1\end{tcolorbox}}
\newcommand{\blindtext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.}
%SteelBlue1, Aquamarine2, DarkOliveGreen2

First list in tcolorbox does not work:
\begin{drama}
  \ex{\blindtext
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \blindtext}
\end{drama}

Second list works well:
\begin{drama}
  \ex{\blindtext
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \blindtext
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \blindtext}
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

The dramatist-package used here is found [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dramatist/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\item` from the `dramatist` package confuses the `tcolorbox` settings as well as the following `enumerate` environment. A `\leavevmode` just before `\begin{tcolorbox}...\end{tcolorbox}` cures this.

I strongly suggest to use `enumitem` package to adjust the spacings of the enumerate and as well as using a special `\newtcolorbox` definition which is easier to maintain than to edit the `\ex` macro over and over again.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %Dummes Absatz-Eingerücke abstellen

\newcommand{\sep}{\\[3mm]}

\newcommand{\ex}[1]{\item \leavevmode\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Lorem Ipsum,colframe=Orange1]#1\end{tcolorbox}}
\newcommand{\blindtext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.}
%SteelBlue1, Aquamarine2, DarkOliveGreen2

First list in tcolorbox does not work:
\begin{drama}
  \ex{\blindtext
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \blindtext}
\end{drama}

Second list works well:
\begin{drama}
  \ex{\blindtext
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \blindtext
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \blindtext}
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works! I am so grateful that you found the time to answer my question, even so fast ;) I was afraid that the question was too specific because of the dramatist-package, but well, thank you! ;)

Comment: @LukeLR: Actually I never heard of the `dramatist` package before (or at least did not use it.) Happy TeXing!

Comment: This was also helpful in my use case of an enumeration including a tcolorbox, which included a nested itemize. I just wrote `\item\leavevmode\begin{tcolorbox}`.